# json_encode with a different result after array_filter

Tags: php, json, array-filter

I want json_encode to return something like this

```
[{key: "value"},{key:"value"},...]
```

Instead I get something like this:

```
{"1": {key: "value"}, "2": {key: "value"}, ...}
```

The result was fine until I did an `array_filter`... Strange...

```
function somefunction($id, $ignore = array()) {
    $ignorefunc = function($obj) use ($ignore) {
        return !in_array($obj['key'], $ignore);
    };

    global $db;

    $q = "Some query";

    $rows = $db->giveMeSomeRows();
    $result = array();
    if ($rows) {
        // this mapping I've always done
        $result = array_map(array('SomeClass', 'SomeMappingFunction'), $rows);
        if (is_array($ignore) && count($ignore) > 0) {
            /////// PROBLEM AFTER THIS LINE ////////
            $result = array_filter($result, $ignorefunc);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So again, if I comment out the `array_filter` I get what I want from `json_encode` on whatever `somefunction` returns, if not I get an JSON-Object.

If I `var_dump` `$result` before and after `array_filter` it's the same type of PHP-array, no strings in the keys and so on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want an `array` but you are getting `json` object because your array does not start from `0` trying using `array_values` to reset the array

Example

```
$arr = array(1=>"a",2=>"Fish");
print(json_encode($arr));
print(json_encode(array_values($arr)));
```

Output

```
{"1":"a","2":"Fish"}
["a","Fish"]
```

Replace

```
 $result = array_filter($result, $ignorefunc);
```

With

```
  $result = array_filter($result, $ignorefunc);
  $result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Baba for the answer, i was having a similar issue and this resolved it!